# CSS (Mobile) fit screen to page

Tags: android, html, ios, css, web

I know it is a long-shot, but i would like to try to see if it is possible to resize (/zoom) the screen to the page size.

I am using a iPhone for my beta-testing, and even if i set the body to 100% it still starts in zoomed (so only half the page is visable). When you zoom out so the entire page is visable, the text is easy to read and i would like to keep it that way.

**It is possible** to set the 100% to be device width (even though i do not know how), but i would like the screen to automaticly zoom to fit the page in it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Check your css you might be having your viewport settings something like this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> Just comment it out and check sometime it automatically fits to device width if not you need to set content variable accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then yes, this is possible - set the device width to a specific width. You can check the user agent to get the specific device being used.

Set the device width to 320 for iPhone displays

For more information check out http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries3.shtml or  http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml